# How do I find the last "1" in each row of a dataframe and record which column it appears in?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has rows consisting of 1s and 0s and I'm stuck trying to append to each row a few summary items, particularly where the last (rightmost) 1 falls. I'd like to add three columns to the dataframe: SUM, LAST, and LAST2 with, respectively: the sum of all the 1s and 0s in that row, the column heading of the last 1 in that row, and the last two characters of the column heading.

This is a smaller sample data set (I'm struggling to get this to look right on the preview):

```
dat<- structure(list(BIRD = c("aaab", "aaam", "aawm", "abum", "aema" ), `2005` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1), `2006` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `2007` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2008` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2009` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `2010` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2011` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `2012` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I would like to end up with is a data frame that has the three additional columns mentioned above.

On my small example data the code below works to extract the column name for the last "1" in each row:

```
 colnames(dat[apply(dat, 1, function(x) max(which(x == 1)))])
```

It returns

```
 [1] "2011" "2011" "2012" "2012" "2011"
```

so then I'd just have to figure out how to append that to the existing dataframe as a new column. (yes I still am very inexperienced but I think I could figure that out).
However, when I try that same colnames() line on my larger data frame (217x64 instead of 5x9) I get this error:

```
Error in `data2months[apply(data2months, 1, function(x) max(which(x == 1)))]`: ! Can't subset columns with `apply(data2months, 1, function(x) max(which(x == 1)))`. ✖ Can't convert from `j` <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision.
```

To my eyes, using `str()`, the two data frames are very similar, just differing in size. Each is a chr vector followed by 8 or 63 num vectors respectively. Any pointers to how best to proceed from here?

Comment: What do you mean by "LAST2: the last two characters of the column heading". Of which column? The one from LAST?

Comment: Yes, I meant the last two characters from the LAST column. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way would be:

```
LAST <- names(dat[-1])[max.col(dat[-1], ties.method = "last")]
LAST2 <- stringr::str_sub(LAST,  -2)
SUM <- rowSums(dat[-1])
cbind(dat, LAST, LAST2, SUM)

  BIRD 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 LAST LAST2 SUM
1 aaab    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0 2011    11   1
2 aaam    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0 2011    11   1
3 aawm    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1 2012    12   5
4 abum    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 2012    12   8
5 aema    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0 2011    11   2
```

Comment: Thank you!  I love this answer and it also works on the larger data set without throwing the error I was seeing before.

Answer (score 1):

And here's a solution with no external dependencies that will fail on package update.

```r
findLastOne <- function(x, digits = 1) {
  last <- max(which(x == 1))
  
  last <- colnames(x)[last]
  
  len <- nchar(last)
  substr(last, start = len - digits + 1, stop = len)
}

dat <- structure(list(BIRD = c("aaab", "aaam", "aawm", "abum", "aema" ), `2005` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1), `2006` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `2007` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2008` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2009` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), `2010` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2011` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `2012` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

dates <- colnames(dat)[grepl("[[:digit:]]", x = colnames(dat))]
dates <- dat[, dates]

dats <- split(dates, f = 1:nrow(dat))

dat$sum <- rowSums(dates)
dat$last <- sapply(dats, FUN = findLastOne, digits = 4)
dat$last2 <- sapply(dats, FUN = findLastOne, digits = 2)

dat

  BIRD 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 sum last last2
1 aaab    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   1 2011    11
2 aaam    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   1 2011    11
3 aawm    1    1    0    0    1    0    1    1   5 2012    12
4 abum    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   8 2012    12
5 aema    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   2 2011    11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the desired output.

First we get long format to identify the last 1, then we right join do the row sum and substring the last two characters from the column name:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = `2005`:`2012`, names_to = "LAST", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(BIRD) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(LAST, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  right_join(dat, by = "BIRD") %>% 
  mutate(LAST2 = substring(LAST, 3,4)) %>% 
  select(BIRD, `2005`:`2012`, contains("LAST")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(SUM = rowSums(select(., -c(BIRD, LAST, LAST2))))
```

```
  BIRD  `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010` `2011` `2012` LAST  LAST2   SUM
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 aaab       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0 2011  11        1
2 aaam       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0 2011  11        1
3 aawm       1      1      0      0      1      0      1      1 2012  12        5
4 abum       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1 2012  12        8
5 aema       1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0 2011  11        2
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `rowwise` and `c_across`, with "tidyselect" `matches` looking for a number without letters.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(SUM = sum(c_across(matches("\\d+"))), 
         LAST = grep("\\d+", colnames(.), value=T)[
                  last(which(c_across(matches("\\d+")) == 1))], 
         LAST2 = substr(LAST, 3, 4)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  print(Inf)
# A tibble: 5 × 12
  BIRD  `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010` `2011` `2012`   SUM LAST 
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 aaab       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0     1 2011 
2 aaam       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0     1 2011 
3 aawm       1      1      0      0      1      0      1      1     5 2012 
4 abum       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     8 2012 
5 aema       1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0     2 2011 
  LAST2
  <chr>
1 11   
2 11   
3 12   
4 12   
5 11
```

Not sure what LAST2 has to show though, guess the last 2 digits of LAST.